# Cannot get "authenticated id" for Cognito credential

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm a AWS beginner, have been studying  Cognito.

I have successfully created a very simple  S3+cognito+lambda(via API gateway) system, where authtoken was used in headers of API call to lambda (after valid sign-in as a cognito user).

Now I'm working on  S3+ cognito + dynamodb  flow without lambda, where a javascript (in browser) directly access dynamodb (after valid sign-in as a cognito user).

[this AWS reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-integrating-user-pools-with-identity-pools.html) 　helped me a lot, but I cannot succeed still..

Here is my code:

```
var cognitoUser =userPool.getCurrentUser();
AWS.config.region = _config.cognito.region;          
cognitoUser.getSession(function(err,result) {
  if (result) {
      var UserPoolId = _config.cognito.userPoolId;  
      console.log("you are now logged in to userpool:"+UserPoolId);

  var provider ='cognitoidp.'+_config.cognito.region+'.amazonaws.com/'+UserPoolId;
  console.log('provider:'+provider);

  AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
           IdentityPoolId: _config.cognito.IdentityPoolId,
              Logins: {
                    provider: result.getIdToken().getJwtToken()
               }
             });

            }
         });
         AWS.config.credentials.get(function(err) {
         if (!err) {
            console.log("Cognito Identify Id: " + AWS.config.credentials.identityId);
         }
         else {
               console.log(err, err.stack);
         }
         });

    ... dynamodb operation..
```

The console log (via chrome developer tool) shows,

```
view.js:78 you are now logged in to userpool:ap-northeast-1_XXXXXXXXX
view.js:81 provider:cognito-idp.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/ap-northeast-1_XXXXXXXXX

cognito-identity.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/:1 POST https://cognito-identity.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/ 400 (Bad Request)
view.js:101 Error: Invalid login token. Issuer doesn't match providerName


    at constructor.i (aws-sdk-2.226.1.min.js:49)
    at constructor.callListeners (aws-sdk-2.226.1.min.js:50)
    at constructor.emit (aws-sdk-2.226.1.min.js:50)
    at constructor.emitEvent (aws-sdk-2.226.1.min.js:50)
    at constructor.e (aws-sdk-2.226.1.min.js:49)
    at a.runTo (aws-sdk-2.226.1.min.js:51)
    at aws-sdk-2.226.1.min.js:51
    at constructor.<anonymous> (aws-sdk-2.226.1.min.js:49)
    at constructor.<anonymous> (aws-sdk-2.226.1.min.js:50)
    at constructor.callListeners (aws-sdk-2.226.1.min.js:50) 

    "NotAuthorizedException: Invalid login token. Issuer doesn't match providerName
```

Without "Logins" params for AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials, it's OK. 
 ("Cognito Identify Id: " shows the returned Id).  But this is "unauthenticated". thus, in order to allow dynamoDB access,  I had to attach the required  policy to the Cognito_myIDPoolName_UnauthRole which had been automatically created during federated identity mgmt. 
I'd like to avoid such extra policy attach to unauthenticated user..
Any advise would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I am facing a similar issue. I have checked my user pool id, identity pool id, app client settings and yet the same error message. Were you able to solve this the right way

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Unfortunately, not able to solve this yet. .  Would greatly appreciate your further comment on finding the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Chiming in a year later, because I feel like such a huge doofus for banging my head on the same problem, your issue is that you're passing along "`provider`" as the key and not the value of the variable of provider:

```
  Logins: {
    [provider]: result.getIdToken().getJwtToken()
  }
```

Hopefully this helps somebody else coming across the same brain fart in the future!